# How many resource rooms are needed for a fully populated vault?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Given a 200 dweller vault, how many resource rooms (food/water; power obviously depends on number of rooms, not dwellers) would be needed to supply the dwellers at a minimum? How many to supply them comfortably (ie., the marked on the left half of the bar)? Cafeteria+water treatment plant vs. super garden+super water purification vs. Nuka-Cola plant?

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that 2 3wide Nuka plants are enough for 200 dwellers, but that's currently unsupported.

Answer (score 1):

**One 3/3 Nuka factory** and **five 2/3 Nuclear reactors** with +5 outfits.

(room width/room level)

[Detailed info about production.](http://m.imgur.com/a/XpGk3)